# Django urlpatterns - too many values to unpack

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Python and Django working on a simple IoT tutorial found in a book. The project is to control a led circuit from a Django app. After I copied of the code, few errors popped up because of the Python and Django version in the book as they are old versions. I am working on Python 3.7.2 and Django 2.1.4 and upon searching, I couldn't find the way to fix my code.

The directory of my project is as follows

Project1

- Project1

  - __init__.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - wsgi.py
- FirstApp

  - admin.py
  - apps.py
  - controller.py
  - index.html
  - models.py
  - serializers.py
  - tests.py
  - views.py

The problem that I am facing is in the urls.py which the code for it is:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from FirstApp import views

admin.autodiscover()

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'mode',views.ModeViewSet)
router.register(r'state',views.StateViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', router.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', 'rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', 'FirstApp.views.home')
]
```

The error traceback is this

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7593e6a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Cpeg389project/Cpeg389project/urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    url(r'^', router.urls),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 13, in url
    return re_path(regex, view, kwargs, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 61, in _path
    urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `include` to add your router URLs as well as the authentication ones:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', views.home)
]
```

See the [DRF Routers docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#using-include-with-routers).

Comment: The namespace argument is causing some trouble as it is giving an unexpected keyword TypeError

Comment: namespace is an argument to include(), not to url().

Comment: Great that worked the error but another error popped up which is this: 
url(r'^home/', 'FirstApp.views.home')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 13, in url
    return re_path(regex, view, kwargs, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Comment: You seem to be using a tutorial written for a **very** old version of Django. You need to use the actual view callable, not a string, in that URL, see my edit.

Comment: The tutorial is really old indeed. That worked like magic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `include()` to add the paths registered in the router:

```
from django.urls import path, include .  # <---------- include()
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from FirstApp import views

admin.autodiscover()

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'mode',views.ModeViewSet)
router.register(r'state',views.StateViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),   # <--------- include()
    url(r'^api-auth/', 'rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', 'FirstApp.views.home')
]
```

Comment: It seems that the Django does not like the namespace argument for some reason. 
This is the Error: 
     url(r'^api-auth/', 'rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework'),
     TypeError: url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'